# Convert formatted string to text

Tags: formatting, text

I'm trying to deal with pasted texts such as ''.
I'd like to convert all the strings formatted like this to simple plain text.
I've seen that pasting text without formatting doesn't work and it seems like there aren't any plugins that solve this problem
Can you help me finding a way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to remove the bold from pasted text? It's not clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Could you [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/419502/edit) with a bit more detail?